# print lists with mkString

Tags: scala

how can I print a list as follows? `[42,[],1]`

`val c : List[List[String]] = List(List("a", "c"), List("b"))`

I have tried with: 
`println(c.mkString("[",",","]"))`
but I dunno, how to do the brackets in the middle.

Comment: looks like an interesting list

Comment: So, basically, you want a mkString method that does a deep recursive mkString on any sub-collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How close is this?

```
val c : List[List[String]] = List(List("a", "c"), List("b"))
c.map(x => x.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString

// String = [a, c][b]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function `s` that makes a string `["a","b"]` from a list `List("a","b")`.

```
val c : List[List[String]] = List(List("a", "c"), List("b"))                            
def s[T](list:List[T]) = list.mkString("[",", ","]")
println(s(c map s))     // [["a", "c"], "b"]
```

Or a more generic option:

```
val d = List(List("a", List("c"), List.empty[String]), List("b"))
def t[T](list: List[T]): String = list.map {
  case a: List[_] => t(a)
  case a          => a
} mkString("[", ", ", "]")

println(t(d))           // [[a, [c], []], [b]]
```